# How to pipe to ifstream in Linux C++ app

Tags: c++, linux

Can anyone explain the statement? what it does?

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(dotnetCommand, "r"), pclose);
```

More, is it possible to pipe to std::ifstream in Linux C++ app? How?

Comment: @MSalters popen only gives you stdout or stdin, never both

Comment: @AlanBirtles: You're right (bidirectional pipes are a thing on BSD, Solaris and Windows, not on Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break it down its easier to understand:

```
// execute dotnetCommand and return a file handle to a pipe for reading from its stdout
// see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/popen.html
FILE* proc = popen(dotnetCommand, "r");
// create a shared pointer that when all references are destroyed calls pclose()
std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(proc, pclose);
```

There is no standard way to create an `ifstream` from a `FILE` handle, `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html allows you to create an `istream` from a `FILE`.

Comment: Neither is there a standard way to create a `std::ifstream` from a Unix file descriptor (`pipe(2)`) but there is very likely an extension to do so.

Comment: Thanks for answer :-)